# Why won't this javascript work on one site, but does on another?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a website up in 2 different places, and on 1 website it works fine, on the other, the code fails to work. Even if I open it in my browser it fails to work.

The script is supposed to change the opacity of an image from 0.6 -> 1 when someone mouse overs the image. Now it works in the original location, in the new location it does not, neither does it work on my pc when I open it directly.

code time:

This is images.js

```
$(function()
{
    $("#footer img").hover
        (
        function()
        {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
        },
        function()
        {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.6"}, "slow");
        }
    );
});
```

This is the code on a page that calls for the above file:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/_resources/javascript/images.js"></script>
```

Then finally the footer where the images are that need to be affected by the code:

```
<div id="footer">
<a href="completed-roofing-works/test.html"><img src="_resources/images/footer-3.jpg" alt="image 2" /></a>
<a href="completed-roofing-works/completed-roofing-works-two.html"><img src="_resources/images/footer-6.jpg" alt="image 1" /></a>
<a href="completed-roofing-works/test.html"><img src="_resources/images/footer-1.jpg" alt="image 3" /></a>
<a href="testimonials/test.html"><img src="_resources/images/footer-4.jpg" alt="Roofers Kent" /></a><a href="testimonials/test.html"><img src="_resources/images/footer-2.jpg" alt="image 4" /></a>
<a href="testimonials/test.html"><img src="_resources/images/footer-5.jpg" alt="image 5" /></a>
</div></div>
```

Just sitting here now the only thing I can think it can be is that Javascript isnt installed, think that could be the case?

Thank you.

:EDIT:

After looking at it, I noticed it could be this script somehow clashing with it:

```
<script language="javascript"> 

 var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
          if (mobile) {
               window.location.replace("mobile/choose.html");
          }


    </script>
```

It comes directly after the code that calls the images.js file

SOLVED THANK YOU:

To anyone with a similar issue in future: Remove the / before the directory name, it appears to dislike this greatly.

Comment: It's not working is not enough for us to help you. Have you got an error from the debugger?

Comment: Could be that *jQuery* isn't included.

Comment: Could be that the two sites reference different versions of jQuery?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt no, this should work in every version of jQuery.

Comment: Or, since the script is declared with an absolute path, is the script accessible on both sites?

Comment: Probably not the case, but you might want to check that your browser isn't enabling/disabling Javascript on a site-by-site basis.

Comment: looking at the debugger, it appears the images.js file isn't even being called. when I check another page, it is there, so it is an issue there i think.

Comment: fixed it, it didn't like the / infront of the directory _resources. Derp move on my part, Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

The code you have there is jQuery. jQuery is a library that requires explicit inclusion.

This is in contrast to [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/), which is so good that browsers have been providing it as standard, without the need for any activation or inclusion, for years.

In this case, however, even Vanilla JS is overkill.

CSS:

```css
#footer img {
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
#footer img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: That's very nice, but doesn't the :hover psuedo class not work for anything other than <a> tags in IE? Maybe its just IE8 and below but depending on the target user it might be a problem. Correct me if I'm wrong though

Comment: @RobQuincey That might have been true last millennium, but it's been okay since IE7!

Comment: @RobQuincey ... It's just occurred to me that the point is moot because `opacity` isn't supported back then XD

Comment: fixed it, it didn't like the / infront of the directory _resources. Derp move on my part, Thank you all for your help.

Also thank you for that bit of code, it looks tasty :)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You'd be surprised what some (myself included) have to support :)